# Dim bulb on timer, even after physically switching off and on

Tags: smart-lights, philips-hue, lighting

I have a pretty simple use case - at least so I thought.

I want a bright light outside my kids' room, that dims on a timer after they've gone to bed, say 11pm. I bought a Philips Hue bulb that's bright enough, and the app lets me set a timer to dim to 50%. So far so good! But if the bulb is turned off and back on, the timer is disabled.

Is there a way to get what I want? I'm happy to use a different bulb, but it must be bright (1600 lumens) - I've tried a couple of cheap Chinese ones which weren't bright enough. Happy to do a bit of coding, but I feel like it shouldn't be necessary. I don't really want to buy a Hue Bridge for my single smart bulb. And I want to keep using the physical switch.

Comment: I'm surprised, you can set a timer on a standalone bulb without a bridge?

Comment: Indeed you can. But the timer gets disabled if power to the bulb is cut.